# Having trouble working with composition function of logs to prove Big-O

Tags: algorithms

The question that I am work on for an hour is

$ n^{lg(lg(n))}\, =\, O((3/2)^{n}) $

I tried to do it by using several theorems, but I know they are not correct. 
Yes I have read the book.

$ n^{lg(lg(n))}\, =\, lg(n)^{lg(n)}$

$ lg(n)^{lg(n)} \, \leq  \, c\cdot(3/2)^{n}  \qquad $  C is a constant let it be 1 in this case

$ lg(lg(n))^{lg(n)}\, \leq \, lg(3/2)^{n} \qquad$ Using property of logs bring down the exponents

$ lg(n) \cdot  lg(lg(n))\, \leq \, n\cdot (lg(3) -1)\qquad $ use some more log properties

$ lg(n) \cdot  lg(lg(n))\, \leq \, n\cdot lg(3) -n\qquad $ simplify

$ lg(n) \cdot  lg(lg(n))\, \leq \, 2^{n\cdot lg(3)-n} \qquad$ My
 only thought is to take everything to the $2^{i}$ power

$ 2^{lg(n) \cdot  lg(lg(n))}\, \leq \, 2^{n\cdot lg(3)-n} \qquad$ This is as for as algebra can take me

If I can prove that $l(n)\cdot lg(lg(n))\, \leq  \, c\cdot n $ then I have shown that  $ \, \, n^{lg(lg(n))}\, =\, O((3/2)^{n}) $

Is my reasoning correct? I am only looking at large values of n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log(x)$ is a strictly increasing function, so $a < b \iff \log a < \log b$.

So $n^{\log \log n} < c(\frac{3}{2})^n$ is equivalent to $(\log \log n) \log n < n \log \frac{3}{2} + \log c,$ by taking logs.

$\log \log n < \log n$, so $(\log \log n) \log n < (\log n)^2$.

So the problem boils down to you knowing/showing that $\log^2 n < n \log \frac{3}{2} + \log c$. Depending on what you know/are allowed to assume, you might use calculus, or your knowledge of the limit $\lim \frac{n}{\log n}$, or just knowledge that $\log^\alpha n \in O (n^\beta)$ for any $\alpha, \beta > 0$ to conclude.